# Using the inputed word only once

Tags: c++, while-loop, user-input

I'm having trouble where a user cannot use the same word after input.
Below is the snippet of a Boggle program I'm working on.

The code below does not work the way I want it to if for example:

(1)The user inputs the word: **fun** --> store into temp[0] --> increment count

(2)The user inputs the word: **fun** --> repeat while loop input for another different input

(3)The user inputs the word: **bye** --> break while loop --> store into temp[1] --> increment count

(4)The user inputs the word: **bye** or **fun** --> will repeat for another input

(5)The user inputs the word: **good** --> store into temp[2] --> increment count

(6)The user inputs the word: **bye** --> repeat while loop for another input,

(7)The user inputs the word: **fun** --> While loop breaks and the word becomes VALID.

You see.. the problem is that it doesn't loop through back to temp[0] to find the word fun again to say its invalid.

Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

```
//seconds is used with time library, but just ignore its declaration
while (seconds < 300){

   string word;
   string temp[100];
   int count = 0;


   cout << "Enter:" << endl;
   cin >> word;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      while (word == temp[i]){
        cout << "Word was already used. Please type another word." << endl;
        cin >> word;
      }
   }

   temp[count] = word;
   count = count + 1;

   if (seconds >= 300)
      break;
}
```

Comment: Why read words in two different places? Read the word once, search the list of existing words, and then either store it or don't store it depending on whether you find the word in the list. Either way, just go on to the next iteration of the main loop.

Comment: or simply push them into a set.

Comment: You reset count to 0 every time you loop. Your for loop will never get entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string word;
string temp[100];
int count = 0;

cout << "Enter:" << endl;
bool found;
do
{
    cin >> word;

    found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] == word)
        {
            found = true;
            cout << "Word was already used. Please type another word." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
while (found);

temp[count++] = word;
```

This will make it so that if the `word` is found anywhere in `temp`, it will ask for a new word and then recheck the entire `temp` array every time. Your original code did not do that, and only checked against the current index `i` even when asking for new input.

Comment: Thank you. I translated it a bit into my Boggle program, and it's working properly.